# How to check AWS lambda references

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to check lambda function references where it use like cognito trigger or dynamodb or lambda authorize in api gateway etc.

is there any option to find all references where it used ?

Comment: `aws lambda get-policy --function-name lambda-arn --output json | jq '.Policy' ` and see the sevices section will show required information

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the Lambda references in the AWS Lambda console as triggers. See a snapshot here showing lambda triggers from S3, API Gateway, SNS and Cognito.

[image]

Comment: Not always true , create a lambda and add cognito pre or post trigger it's not showing as trigger .